# setData and setCategory highcharts from rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I'm using highcharts 3.0.1 with ruby on rails.

basically i have finally this javascript ( in an ajax/remote request) :

```
var chart = $('#my_bar_div').highcharts();
chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(["cat1", "cat2", "cat4"]);
chart.series[0].setData([6.0,7.0,8.0]);
```

ruby version _updatechart.js.erb:

```
var chart = $('#my_bar_div').highcharts();
chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(<%= @qids.to_s.html_safe %>);
chart.series[0].setData(<%= @average_values.to_json %>);
```

i'm going back from 6 to 3 categories/rows, I use a vertical column chart:

```
@bar = LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('column') do |f|
  f.series(:name=>'Punkte',:data=> @average_values )   
  f.title({ :text=>"Auswertung Fragen " + @theobjects.name })

  ###  Options for Bar
  f.options[:chart][:defaultSeriesType] = "bar"
  f.plot_options({:series=>{:stacking=>"normal"}, :bar => { :dataLabels => { :enabled => true }}})
  f.options[:xAxis] = {:plot_bands => "none", :title=>{:text=>""}, :categories => @qids}
  f.options[:yAxis] = {:title => { :text =>'Punkte', :align =>'high'}, :labels => { :overflow => 'justify' } }
end
```

it resizes the categories, but does not redraw the columns, I tried almost everything without success.

Maybe you got any ideas?

Thanks, Patrick

Comment: I'm not sure where is the problem. You want to plot three categories, and three bars, right? Is that working?

Comment: yes, thats working, i'm trying to update the data, but the bars disapear when updating the data, i can update the categories

Comment: Could you post example of data which you are trying to update? Make sure that data is sorted ascending (for xAxis), values are numbers and doesn't contain empty strings or NaN's.

Comment: here is a the data: `var chart = $('#my_bar_div').highcharts();
chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(["Wie ist es?", "Wie geht es dir?"]);
chart.series[0].setData([5.5,6.0]);`

Comment: here is a fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/BCRyP/
The code is copy & paste from the generated gem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed example: http://jsfiddle.net/BCRyP/4/

1) `"plotBands": "none"` -> remove that or use {}

2) Use the same variable's name:

```
var chart;
$(document).ready(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    jQuery("#button").on("click", function () {
        chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(["Wie geht es?", "How is your mam?"], true);
        chart.series[0].setData([5.5, 6.0], true);
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you! it was that plotBands option, this was from copy & paste :(

the variable name was a typo, thanks again